# D3 cluster: can lines make no crossing?

Tags: d3.js

Here is an example of d3 clustering:http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570
We can see the lines cross each other like this：

[image: We can see the lines cross each other like this]

How can it be avoided?

D3 tree layout http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033can avoid line crossing but the leafs are not finished on one line.

[image]

Can any layout be modified to satisfy both conditions:
1、no line crossing
2、leafs are on one line

Thanks!

Comment: What did you mean `leafs are not finished on one line.`?

Comment: In the picture above, where、xor and TimeScale are all leaves, they are not on one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try looking [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ff91c1558bc570b08539547ccc90050b) for an example (from mbostock too) of one using - I believe - the same dataset but not colliding in the way you describe.